# How to share MS Project macro?

Tags: ms-project, excel-macro

I have created a macro in my MS- Project. I am admin. Now how can I make it available to be used by other MS- Project users of my enterprise? Macro is created in Global file/template.

Comment: Also, my environment is Project Online.

Comment: This form is focused on SharePoint. You might want to do a search for "Microsoft Project forums". A couple possibilities are https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions,  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/home